# Importing date audit fields from Salesforce into SQL Server

Tags: integration, data-export

I have exported LeadHistory data from Workbench into a local CSV. I am now trying to import that via SQL Server's import wizard, but am getting stuck on the `CreatedDate` field. The wizard suggests the source field is of type DT_DATE and wants to map it to SQL Server's DateTime, yet throws an error on import.

> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Source -
>   LeadHistory_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source
>   Output].Columns[CreatedDate]" failed because error code 0xC0209084
>   occurred, and the error row disposition on "Source -
>   LeadHistory_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source
>   Output].Columns[CreatedDate]" specifies failure on error. An error
>   occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There
>   may be error messages posted before this with more information about
>   the failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I have tried various other date options for the source ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)):

- DT_DBTIME2
- DT_DBTIMESTAMP
- DT_DBTIMESTAMP2
- DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET

All of these map to SQL Server's datetime, which is what we've used in the past.

A sample source value looks like this: `2013-07-18T20:28:27.000Z`

Any thoughts on how to get the import wizard to handle this? Do I need to pre-process the field and transform it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I ended up taking was to load the data as a string into a staging table and then use SQL Server's `CONVERT` function:

```
CONVERT(datetime, CreatedDate, 127)
```

Where 127 is the format code for ISO8601 with time zone Z. I'm sure a full SSIS package could have handled the conversion, but for a one-time data load that was worth the effort.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know SSIS supports ISO8601 (the Salesforce format) since 2008.  DT_DBTIMESTAMP should be the one.  Try removing the Z at the end though - not sure if SQL Server understands that.